Cygwin: compile C API calls for Python with gcc
I have a bash script for compiling a Python project with C API calls (SWIG):
swig -python trace_skeleton.i
gcc -O3 -c trace_skeleton.c trace_skeleton_wrap.c -I/usr/local/x/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
gcc $(python3-config --ldflags) -dynamiclib *.o -o _trace_skeleton.so -I/usr/local/x/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib -undefined dynamic_lookup

The script links to some user's Python libs on Linux. On Cygwin I installed bash, swig, gcc and Python (C:\cygwin64\bin\python3.9.exe). I also have a separate full Python install (C:\Python310). When I run bash, obviously I get an error, since gcc can't locate Python.h on Win:
trace_skeleton_wrap.c:194:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory 194 | # include <Python.h>

In compile.sh, how do I point gcc to my (Win) Python libs? Do I use Cygwin's Python, or my full-install Python?

Try adding CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=1 to your windows user environment, and restart all your cygwin terminal sessions. This removes windows path folders from the cygwin PATH variable. They are still present in the ORIGINAL_PATH variable if you really really need to add them into your path. You will need the cygwin python-dev package installed, and you may need to add -I or a $(python3-config ...) to get the python include folder into the gcc command line. When building for cygwin, you must not have any reference to your windows version of python.

Try to install python39-devel package.

Philippe, Doug, Thanks, I'll give it a try later today.
